# Python Get Elements of List if Matched

Tags: list, python-3.x

Given the following list:

```
colors=['#c85200','#5f9ed1','lightgrey','#ffbc79','#006ba4','dimgray','#ff800e','#a2c8ec'
,'grey','salmon','cyan','silver']
```

And this list:

```
Hospital=['a','b','c','d']
```

After I get the number of colors based on the length of the list - 'Hospital':

```
num_hosp=len(Hospital)
colrs=colors[:num_hosp]

colrs
['#c85200', '#5f9ed1', 'lightgrey', '#ffbc79']
```

...and zip the lists together:

```
hcolrs=zip(Hospitals,colrs)
```

Next, I'd like to be able to select 1 or more colors from hcolrs if given a list of one or more hospitals from 'Hospitals'.

Like this:

```
newHosps=['a','c'] #input
newColrs=['#c85200','lightgrey'] #output
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the result of `zip` to the `dict` constructor to make lookup simple/fast:

```
# Don't need to slice colors; zip stops when shortest iterable exhausted
hosp_to_color = dict(zip(Hospitals, colors))
```

then use it:

```
newHosps = ['a','c']
newColrs = [hosp_to_color[h] for h in newHosps]
```